# binding object with multiple attributes to select form java

Tags: jsp, select, binding, attributes

I am trying to display select form from object Author with two attributes (firstName, lastName). Cannot add two attributes to itemLabel. When I tried to display those attrubutes from list then there is no binding as database is not updated with this attributes. How can I put multiple attributes to select form with binding?

```
Author <form:select itemValue="id" itemLabel="firstName" path="author"
             items="${authors}" />  




@Controller
public class ArticleController {


    @Autowired
    public ArticleDao articleDao;

    @Autowired
    public AuthorDao authorDao;

    @RequestMapping("list-articles")
    public String allArticles(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("article", articleDao.findAllArticle());
        return "articleList";
    }
    @RequestMapping("add-article")
    public String addArticle(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("article", new Article());
        return "add-article";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "add-article", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveArticle(@ModelAttribute("article") Article article, BindingResult bindingResult){
        articleDao.saveArticle(article);
        return "redirect:/list-articles";
    }
    @ModelAttribute("authors")
    public List<Author> authors() {
        return this.authorDao.findAllAuthors();
    }
}






@Entity
public class Article {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(length = 200)
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne
    private Author author;
//setters & getters
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer is this:

display List into view and then back to controller bind to object by adding parameter itemValue="id"

```
<form:select items="${authors}" multiple="true" path="author" itemValue="id" class="form-Control" />
```

Comment: my understanding is that this is not perfect solution as the list displays without dropdown feature

Comment: ok, got it now - to have a feature of dropdown list you need to remove "mulitple=true""